# AWS Lambda timeout using Fastify and Serverless Framework

Tags: typescript, serverless, fastify

I developed a new architecture for my services using Serverless Framework and Fastify.

This is my code.

**serverless.yml**

```
functions:
  app:
    name: ${self:service}--${self:provider.stage}
    handler: src/app/bootstrap/lambda.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /v1/users/{any+}
          method: '*'
      - httpApi:
          path: /v1/users
          method: '*'
```

**lambda.ts**

```
import awsLambdaFastify from '@fastify/aws-lambda'

import { buildFastify } from '../app'
import { config } from '../config'

const fastify = buildFastify({
  logger: {
    level: config.app.logger.level,
  },
})

const proxy = awsLambdaFastify(fastify)

export const handler = proxy
```

**app.ts**

```
// Imports...

let fastify: FastifyInstance | null

export const buildFastify = (opts: FastifyServerOptions = {}): FastifyInstance => {
  fastify = Fastify(opts)

  // ...plugins...

  fastify.register(getMe, { prefix: `v1/users` })

  return fastify
}
```

**getMe.ts**

```
import { FastifyReply, FastifyRequest } from 'fastify'
import { FastifyPluginAsync } from 'fastify'
import { FromSchema } from 'json-schema-to-ts'
import { FastifyRequestUser } from 'types'

import { container } from '../provider'
import { schema } from '../schemas/schema'
import { IUser } from '../../domain/interfaces/IUser'
import { UserService } from '../services/user-service'
import { GenericException } from '../../lib/exceptions/generic-exception'

const routes: FastifyPluginAsync = async (fastify, _opts): Promise<void> => {
  fastify.get(
    '/me',
    {
      preValidation: fastify.authenticate,
      schema: schema,
    },
    async (_req: FastifyRequest, _res: FastifyReply) => {
      try {
        const service = container.get<UserService>('userService')
        const request = _req as FastifyRequestUser
        console.log(request.user.sub)

        const user: IUser = await service.findById(request.user.sub)

        const response: FromSchema<typeof schema.response['200']> = {
          _id: user._id,
          firstName: user.firstName,
          lastName: user.lastName,
          email: user.email,
          picture: user.picture,
        }

        return response
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        throw new GenericException('Generic error')
      }
    },
  )
}

export default routes
```

Everything works fine when run locally but when I test it on AWS it times out and returns "service unavailable" error.

Why would this happen? how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you look at the compiled code? What did it `exports`?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was really easy. I just had to change the `lambda.ts` file setting `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` parameter to false.

```
import awsLambdaFastify from '@fastify/aws-lambda'

import { buildFastify } from '../app'
import { config } from '../config'

const fastify = buildFastify({
  logger: {
    level: config.app.logger.level,
  },
})

const proxy = awsLambdaFastify(fastify, {
  callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: false,
})

export const handler = proxy
```